# Oauth2 - JDBC Implementation How to change database table names

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have implemented OAuth2 with Spring security following [this link.](http://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-spring-oauth2-angularjs) Now there are several tables with following names - oauth_client_details , oauth_code , oauth_client_token and etc. Now what i need to do is to change these names. with a prefix (like "security_"). How can i do that ?

Answer (score 4):

1) `JdbcClientDetailsService` implements `ClientDetailsService` which uses the `oauth_client_details` table in hard-coded JDBC PreparedStatements.

2) `JdbcClientTokenServices` implements `ClientTokenServices` which uses the `oauth_client_token` table in hard-coded JDBC PreparedStatements.

3) `JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices` implements `AuthorizationCodeServices` which uses the `oauth_code` table in hard-coded JDBC PreparedStatements.

In your `Oauth2Config.java` or `SecurityConfig` (whatever you call it), when you wire up your Services, you could use a custom Service that you hand-jammed that implements the same interface as the Service you are trying to override.

So... If you wanted to store your Client tokens in a table called `security_oauth_tokens`, then you could just implement your own `ClientTokenServices` and wire it into your configuration instead.

**Here is a rough example of how you could start to create a `CustomClientTokenServices`, that uses spring Repositories:**

```
@Component
public class RepositoryClientTokenServices implements ClientTokenServices
{

    @Autowired
    TokenRepository repository;

    private ClientKeyGenerator keyGenerator = new DefaultClientKeyGenerator();

    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken getAccessToken(final OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource, final Authentication authentication)
    {

        String accessToken = keyGenerator.extractKey(resource, authentication);
        TokenEntity tokenEntity = this.repository.findByAuthenticationId(accessToken);

        if (tokenEntity == null && LOG.isInfoEnabled())
        {
            LOG.debug("Failed to find access token for authentication " + authentication);
            return null;
        }

        return new DefaultOAuth2AccessToken(tokenEntity.getValue());
    }

    @Override
    public void saveAccessToken(final OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource, final Authentication authentication, final OAuth2AccessToken accessToken)
    {
      //use the repository to save the token
    }

    @Override
    public void removeAccessToken(final OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource, final Authentication authentication)
    {
      //use repository to remove the token
    }
}
```

**But! Probably the easiest way would be to create a `CustomJDBCClientTokenServices`, that just does a find/replace on the table name like this:**

```
@Component
public class CustomJdbcClientTokenServices implements ClientTokenServices {

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(JdbcClientTokenServices.class);

    private static final String DEFAULT_ACCESS_TOKEN_INSERT_STATEMENT = "insert into security_oauth_client_token (token_id, token, authentication_id, user_name, client_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    private static final String DEFAULT_ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_AUTHENTICATION_SELECT_STATEMENT = "select token_id, token from security_oauth_client_token where authentication_id = ?";

    private static final String DEFAULT_ACCESS_TOKEN_DELETE_STATEMENT = "delete from security_oauth_client_token where authentication_id = ?";

    private String insertAccessTokenSql = DEFAULT_ACCESS_TOKEN_INSERT_STATEMENT;

    private String selectAccessTokenSql = DEFAULT_ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_AUTHENTICATION_SELECT_STATEMENT;

    private String deleteAccessTokenSql = DEFAULT_ACCESS_TOKEN_DELETE_STATEMENT;

    private ClientKeyGenerator keyGenerator = new DefaultClientKeyGenerator();

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public CustomJdbcClientTokenServices(DataSource dataSource) {
        Assert.notNull(dataSource, "DataSource required");
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public void setClientKeyGenerator(ClientKeyGenerator keyGenerator) {
        this.keyGenerator = keyGenerator;
    }

    public OAuth2AccessToken getAccessToken(OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource, Authentication authentication) {

        OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = null;

        try {
            accessToken = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(selectAccessTokenSql, new RowMapper<OAuth2AccessToken>() {
                public OAuth2AccessToken mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                    return SerializationUtils.deserialize(rs.getBytes(2));
                }
            }, keyGenerator.extractKey(resource, authentication));
        }
        catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
            if (LOG.isInfoEnabled()) {
                LOG.debug("Failed to find access token for authentication " + authentication);
            }
        }

        return accessToken;
    }

    public void saveAccessToken(OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource, Authentication authentication,
                                OAuth2AccessToken accessToken) {
        removeAccessToken(resource, authentication);
        String name = authentication==null ? null : authentication.getName();
        jdbcTemplate.update(
                insertAccessTokenSql,
                new Object[] { accessToken.getValue(), new SqlLobValue(SerializationUtils.serialize(accessToken)),
                        keyGenerator.extractKey(resource, authentication), name,
                        resource.getClientId() }, new int[] { Types.VARCHAR, Types.BLOB, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR,
                        Types.VARCHAR });
    }

    public void removeAccessToken(OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource, Authentication authentication) {
        jdbcTemplate.update(deleteAccessTokenSql, keyGenerator.extractKey(resource, authentication));
    }

    public void setInsertAccessTokenSql(String insertAccessTokenSql) {
        this.insertAccessTokenSql = insertAccessTokenSql;
    }

    public void setSelectAccessTokenSql(String selectAccessTokenSql) {
        this.selectAccessTokenSql = selectAccessTokenSql;
    }

    public void setDeleteAccessTokenSql(String deleteAccessTokenSql) {
        this.deleteAccessTokenSql = deleteAccessTokenSql;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because this names are hard-coded inside client&provider classes:

`"oauth_client_details"` in `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.JdbcClientDetailsService`,

`"oauth_code"` in `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.code.JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices`

`"oauth_client_token"` in `org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.JdbcClientTokenServices`

and so on,

you will probably have to manually rewrite those classes and bind them to your own client&provider classes.

(This doesn't look easy though).

Answer (score 0):

When creating the JDBCTokenStore in this fragment:

```
@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource());
}
```

You can set different values for the SQL queries that the `JDBCTokenStore` has to issue to the database before returning the object. Take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/store/JdbcTokenStore.java): you will see different setters to each of the queries used.

Answer (score 0):

It's so simple.
Follow these steps:

1. find **JdbcClientDetailsService** and **JdbcTokenStore** from oauth2 jar file or user  on this classes in **spring-security.xml** config file.

```xml
<bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStor*">
     <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

2. make a copy of each class and create new one in your program. then change name of tables and columns to your appropriate names (I change table and column names).

```java
public class CustomeJdbcTokenStore implements TokenStore { 
    private String insertAccessTokenSql = "insert oauthAccessToken
        (tokenId, token, authenticationId, username, clientId, authentication, refreshToken) 
        values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    private String selectAccessTokenSql = "select tokenId, token from 
         oauthAccessToken where tokenId = ?";

    private String selectAccessTokenAuthenticationSql = "select tokenId, authentication from 
         oauthAccessToken where tokenId = ?";
```

3. Add new class to **spring-security.xml** file.

```xml
<bean id="tokenStore" class="ir.hossein.irtms.service.CustomJdbcTokenStore**">
     <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```